# Get all <thspan> contents in Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

Say that I have a piece of HTML code that looks like this:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <thspan class="sentence">He</thspan>
        <thspan class="sentence">llo</thspan>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I wanted to get the content of both  and connect them into a string in Python Selenium.

My current code looks like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

thspans = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "sentence")
context = ""
for thspan in thspans:
    context.join(thspan.text)
```

The code can run without any problem, but the context variable doesn't contain anything. How can I get the content of both  and connect them into a string in Python Selenium?

Comment: Use this line `context += thspan.text` instead of using  `context.join(thspan.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context += thspan.text` instead of using `context.join(thspan.text)` just like @Rajagopalan said

Answer (score 0):

You were not redirecting the browser to the page you actually want to scrape the data from. And you were misusing the `.join` method. Here is a code that will work for you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
# Put the absolute path to your html file if you are working locally, or
# the URL of the domain you want to scrap
browser.get('file:///your/absolute/path/to/the/html/code/index.html')

thspans = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "sentence")
context = ''
print('thspans', thspans, end='\n\n')
for thspan in thspans:
    context += thspan.text
print(context)
```